# Redmine throws an error

Tags: apache, redmine, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

**Error:**

> [Fri Apr 17 22:40:32 2015] [warn] [client 1.52.63.23] (104)Connection
>   reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
>
> [Fri Apr 17 22:40:32 2015] [error] [client 1.52.63.23] Premature end of script headers: dispatch.fcgi

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: can you please post the relevant code and configuration?

Answer (score 0):

@Lucky

Code dispatch.fcgi

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
    parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
    env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
    env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(RedmineApp::Application)
```

Code fcgid.conf

```
# This is the Apache server configuration file for providing FastCGI support
# through mod_fcgid
#
# Documentation is available at
# http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

# Use FastCGI to process .fcg .fcgi & .fpl scripts
AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl

# Sane place to put sockets and shared memory file
FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
FcgidProcessLifeTime 8200
FcgidIOTimeout 8200
FcgidConnectTimeout 300
</IfModule>
```